# Ag Grid fails to load when adding valueFormatter in react functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am displaying some data using AgGrid in react functional components. For the values which are objects i am trying to display their json values for which i used valueFormatter option in colDefs as shown in code below. But when i use this , i get an error :

```
Error: ag-Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout, eg instead of api.refreshView(), call setTimeout(function(){api.refreshView(),0}). To see what part of your code that caused the refresh check this stacktrace.
```

I don't get above error if i don't use valueFormatter option. I know i need to load the grid when its ready according to error but i am not sure how to do it in react functional components.

Code example :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { AgGridReact, ICellRendererReactComp } from "ag-grid-react";
function Test(props) {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(null);
  const defaultColDef = {
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    resizable: true,
  };
  const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Sample Key',
      field: 'sampleKey',
      valueFormatter: (val) => JSON.stringify(val),
    },
    //OTHER COLDEFS
  ]
  
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="card mt-2 p-3 bg-red shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
          <div
            className="ag-theme-balham"
            style={{ height: "500px", width: "100%" }}
          >
            <AgGridReact
              columnDefs={columnDefs}
              rowData={rowData}
            ></AgGridReact>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export { Test };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is: `JSON.stringify(val)`

you're trying to use stringify in a circular structure.

[image: you can see the output of val]

So if you'll change it to `val.value` it works for you.

You can see an example
[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-demo-i8gp5)